# Express Handlesbars, jQuery and getting globals into jQuery through node.js

Tags: jquery, node.js, express-handlebars

So, I am trying to get data into a global variable inside of my jQuery file. I assign a global variable in node.js:

```
// Global Variables
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  if (req.user) {
    res.locals.user = req.user.meta || null;
  }
  next();

  // New.find().sort({date: -1}).then(results => {
  //   res.locals.news = results;
  //   next();
  // });
});
```

What I am tring to do here is use `user` inside of jQuery using the correct data. Of course the data for the handlebars template passes through correctly:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/game.css">

{{> game/_header}}
<div class="container-fluid">
  {{log user}}
</div>
<script src="/js/g.js"></script>
```

I am having trouble getting these values into my jQuery file, I am not really going to bother posting what I've tried because I am just trying to use `user` which I know it wouldn't work but thats the best idea I had. So my question is this: do I need to fetch this data somehow? Or can I pass it easily and I am something super simple.